# image sample is black when converted

Tags: php, image, gd

When i upload a file (.jpg) and i do a `var_dump($_FILES['img'])` i will get something like this:

```
array
  'name' => string 'help_clip_image020.jpg' (length=22)
  'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
  'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpfa9gSr' (length=14)
  'error' => int 0
  'size' => int 35504
```

However with this code:

```
include("resize-class.php");

// *** 1) Initialise / load image
$resizeObj = new resize($_FILES['img']);

// *** 2) Resize image (options: exact, portrait, landscape, auto, crop)
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 200, 'crop');

// *** 3) Save image
$resizeObj -> saveImage('sample-resized.jpg', 100);
```

I will get an image that is black filled. But with an absolute path like:

```
$resizeObj = new resize('http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image1.jpg');
```

all works well. So my question is: I need to store the image in the host before convert it? I want to avoid this because i only need the thumbnail.

Also:  `$_FILES['img']['tmp_name']` didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need something like this:

```
 if(move_uploaded_file($img['tmp_name'], $path.$yourImgName_extension)){
            $resizeObj = new resize($path.$yourImgName_extension);

            $resizeObj -> resizeImage(200, 200, 'crop');

            $resizeObj -> saveImage($path.'sample-resized.jpg', 100);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

use $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

your solutions uses the whole array as parameter

Comment: I had already tested what you post before the question, and didn't work. thanks

Comment: btw. what resize class do you use ?

Comment: i thin you might have to copy the picture first in order to give it an extension. as far as i have read through the examples there, the function looks for the file extension in order to determine what to do. that means  string '/tmp/phpfa9gSr' wont work for the class also it is a jpg in the end